# How to access a partition key in a lambda function?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have used getItem inside my lambda function.

```
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: "2012-10-08"});

let params = {
            TableName: "Probability",
            Key: {
                index: randomItemProbability
            }
        };
let item = ddb.getItem(params);
//access partition key of item below
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a callback which allows you to react to the event "the database has provided the result" like this:

```
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: "2012-10-08"});

let params = {
            TableName: "Probability",
            Key: {
                index: randomItemProbability
            }
        };
let item = ddb.getItem(params, (err, data) => {
    // Do whatever your need with err and data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({region: region});
const dynamodb = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
...
invoiceId = event.queryStringParameters.invoiceId;
var params = {
  TableName:TableName,
  Key:{
   id: invoiceId
  }
};
const invoice = await dynamodb.get(params).promise();
if(invoice){
  const item = invoice.Item
  console.log('item id', item.id);
}
```